# How to resolve the nginx index redirect to the index of my wordpress migrated in the container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I am facing a redirect issue (I believe it is), I followed the tutorial https://stephenafamo.com/blog/moving-wordpress-docker-container/ and only the nginx index appears and not from my wordpress application. Can someone tell me how I can solve it?

Comment: what do you mean with "only the nginx index appears and not from my wordpress application"? It might be useful to post your setup (docker-compose, nginx config, etc) since you might have made a mistake in there.

Comment: on the index, I mean that when installing nginx normally (external) and to test if this same installed puts itself in the browser localhost, in case it is right. However, in my wordpress container, I put my application but only the nginx index appears. I'll show you the code.

Comment: server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/teste/src/25anos;

    server_name teste teste;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:1212;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Comment: I followed this tutorial. "https://stephenafamo.com/blog/moving-wordpress-docker-container/"

Comment: The tutorial mentions port 1234 and you changed it to 1212. So obviously you made changes and that is why you should post your configuration if you really want help. What I think happened is that you missed the steps to enable the site and restart nginx (just after the nginx conf setup). If it's not that please update the post (don't add code in the comments)

Comment: yes, I made changes, but to do various tests in order to solve my problem and all I could not change the nginx index. I think the problem is the communication of nginx with wordpress.

Comment: but I'll send the codes. I'll just organize.